# optaplanner Vehicle Routing with time window

Tags: optaplanner

I have two questions for the right use of Vehicle Routing with time window.

1. If I have a due Time of nine o'clock in the morning, how must I write it in the vrp file?
2. If I have a service Duration of 30 minutes, how must I write this in the vrp file?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The VRP files are following [the academic format described here](http://neo.lcc.uma.es/vrp/vrp-instances/description-for-files-of-solomons-instances/).

Comment: then I have one more question: what is the entity of the time windows?

Comment: What you make it really - if everything is in seconds, its seconds, if everything is in minutes, it's minutes. Use road distances in the same unit because air distances use eucledian distance which aren't in a time unit, so they mess up the score calc.

Comment: Hey M2207 and Geoffrey - the site doesnt open any longer. Do you have any reference links?

Comment: See optaplanner docs chapter 3 about VRP, there's a link there IIRC. They changed their URL at some point.

Comment: Or just use optaweb-vehicle-routing so you get a pretty maps UI :)

Comment: I am tweaking the VRPTW example for our requirement of delivering services based on customer appointment. for e.g. 9 am to 11 pm. 11 to 1 pm and so on. In some cases there is a day overlap because of night services at certain premises. for e.g. starting 1st Jan 2019 11 pm to 1 am next day. How do we manage the time entity. Should it be date time converted to long with base period like the EPOCH?